# Splash screen scaling issue IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, splash-screen

I've built an ionic app, Splash screen is getting scaled(Disorted) in ios.
When i run "ionic Cordova resources", Images that are created in /resources/ios/splash/ are looking fine. But when I run app in simulator or physical device using xCode, Image is getting scaled and showing zoomed.

This is my app info:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v8.9.1
npm        : 5.5.1 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Please help!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: You solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What is your **resources** folder looking like? May I share the structure of mine with you?

```
/resources
-- /android
-- icon.png
-- icon.png.md5
-- /ios
-- splash.png
-- splash.png.md5
```

First of all, *empty* your **resources** folder now. Put only 2 source files - `icon.png (1024x1024)` & `splash.png (2732x2732)` there. Next, run `ionic cordova resources`. That would result in just like the above structure.

Hope this might help you.